# Degeneration formula and Donaldson-Floer theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Is there a relation between the degeneration formula of GW Invariants of Jun Li and the Donaldson-Floer theory? Is there an example / discussion anywhere of/on this relation?